# how make the UIView height equal to its subview's additional height, so that it can easily scroll till the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a situation where i have following view layout.

```
-UIViewcontroller

  -SCrollView

    -UIView(outer)

      -buttons

      -labels 

      -UIView(inner)

           -labels

           -buttons

       -buttons
```

the inner `UIView` height can be any longer as content inside is dynamically added.
So the main issue is i can not scroll till the end of the content, instead i can only scroll till the height of inner `UIView`.

**NOTE - I am using auto layout**

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Cihan Tek please tell me what constraints should i use.

Comment: Check out my more detailed answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should change the frame of your inner view dynamically based on the content you are adding. According to your inner view hierarchy, you have `label` and `button`. You might be setting some dynamic text on `label` and also doing some manipulation with `button` . Use the following method to get the height of the text ,

```
- (CGSize)getHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
if (text) {
    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
    size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
}
return size;
}
```

Here `font` is the font you set to button and label. Call this method by passing the text added on `label` and `button`.  `CGSize` has a `height` property , add `height` value of `label` and `button`. Now set this sum `height` to `innerView` by calling `innerView.frame.size.height = <height>`. This increase the height of your innerView based on content inside that.

Comment: it says "Expression is not assignable", when tried this code nnerView.frame.size.height = <height>.

Comment: in place of '<height>' set you height value which is a added sum of label height and button height. I mentioned <height> to set some value here. It should be like this innerView.frame.size.height = 300. Here 300 is height value.

Comment: i can understand that, and did the same. it is showing the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your buttons in the bottom inside a container view and add the following constraints to the outerView (assuming that the new container you've added is called "buttonContainer"):

- A vertical spacing constraint between the bottom of innerView and the top of the buttonContainer.
- A vertical spacing constraint between the bottom of the buttonContainer and the bottom of the outerView.
- Horizontal spacing constraints between between the buttonContainer and outerView to force it to full width.

When using AutoLayout, you have to have enough constraints to properly define the contentSize of the scrollView.
For more information about using AutoLayout with UIScrollView, check out the following links by Apple:

[Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html)

[UIScrollView and Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)